# MongoDB one way replication

Tags: mongodb

Need some way to push data from clients database to central database.Basically, there are several instances of MongoDB running on remote machines [clients] , and need some method to periodically update central mongo database with newly added and modified documents in clients.it must replicate its records to the single central server

Eg:

If I have 3 mongo instances running on 3 machines each having data of 10GB then after the data migration 4th machine's mongoDB must have 30GB of data.  And  cenral mongoDB machine must get periodically updated with data of all those 3 machines. But these 3 machines not only get new documents but existing documents in them may get updated. I would like the central mongoDB machine also to get these updations.

Answer (score 6):

Your desired replication strategy is not formally supported by MongoDB.

A [MongoDB replica set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/) consists of a single primary with asynchronous replication to one or more secondary servers in the same replica set.  You cannot configure a replica set with multiple primaries or replication to a different replica set.

However, there are a few possible approaches for your use case depending on how actively you want to keep your central server up to date and the volume of data/updates you need to manage.

#### Some general caveats:

- Merging data from multiple standalone servers can create unexpected conflicts.  For example, unique indexes would not know about documents created on other servers.
- Ideally the data you are consolidating will still be separated by a unique database name per origin server so you don't have strange crosstalk between disparate documents that happen to have the same namespace and `_id` shared by different origin servers.

### Approach #1: use `mongodump` and `mongorestore`

If you just need to periodically sync content to your central server, one way to do so is using [`mongodump` and `mongorestore`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/backups/#using-binary-database-dumps-for-backups).  You can schedule a periodic `mongodump` from each of your standalone instances and use `mongorestore` to import them into the central server.

#### Caveats:

- There is a [`--db` parameter](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongorestore/#cmdoption-mongorestore--db) for `mongorestore` that allows you to restore into a different database from the original name (if needed)
- `mongorestore` only performs inserts into the existing database (i.e. does **not** perform updates or upserts). If existing data with the same `_id` already exists on the target database, mongorestore will not replace it.
- You can use `mongodump` options such as [`--query`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongodump/#cmdoption-mongodump--query) to be more selective on data to export (for example, only select recent data rather than all)
- If you want to limit the amount of data to dump & restore on each run (for example, only exporting "changed" data), you will need to work out how to handle updates and deletions on the central server.

Given the caveats, the simplest use of this approach would be to do a full dump & restore (i.e. using [`mongorestore --drop`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongorestore/#cmdoption-mongorestore--drop)) to ensure all changes are copied.

### Approach #2: use a tailable cursor with the MongoDB `oplog`.

If you need more realtime or incremental replication, a possible approach is [creating tailable cursors](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-tailable-cursor/) on the MongoDB replication [`oplog`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication/#replica-set-oplog-sizing).

This approach is basically "roll your own replication".  You would have to write an application which tails the oplog on each of your MongoDB instances and looks for changes of interest to save to your central server.  For example, you may only want to replicate changes for selective namespaces (databases or collections).

A related tool that may be of interest is the experimental [Mongo Connector](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/29127828146/introducing-mongo-connector) from 10gen labs.  This is a Python module that provides an interface for tailing the replication `oplog`.

#### Caveats:

- You have to implement your own code for this, and learn/understand how to work with the `oplog` documents
- There may be an alternative product which better supports your desired replication model "out of the box".

Comment: Thanks for the info about tailable cursors, this is nearly exactly what I was looking for. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You should be aware that there are only replica set for doing replication there a replicat set always means: one primary, multiple secondary. Write *always* go to the primary server. Appearently you want multi-master replication which is not supported by MongoDB. So you want to look into a different technology like CouchDB or CouchBase. MongoDB is barrel burst here.

Comment: He (and I) wants only a one way replication, basically 'insert' mirroring on each db, this is not a 'real' replication with all associated technical difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a way since MongoDB 3.6 to achieve your goal: [Change Streams](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/changeStreams/).

> Change streams allow applications to access real-time data changes without the complexity and risk of tailing the oplog. Applications can use change streams to subscribe to all data changes on a single collection, a database, or an entire deployment, and immediately react to them. Because change streams use the aggregation framework, applications can also filter for specific changes or transform the notifications at will.

There are some configuration options that affect whether you can use Change Streams or not, so please read about them.

Another option is [Delayed Replica Set Members](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/replica-set-delayed-member/).

> Because delayed members are a "rolling backup" or a running "historical" snapshot of the data set, they may help you recover from various kinds of human error. For example, a delayed member can make it possible to recover from unsuccessful application upgrades and operator errors including dropped databases and collections.

[Hidden Replica Set Members](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/replica-set-hidden-member/) may be another option to consider.

> A hidden member maintains a copy of the primary's data set but is invisible to client applications. Hidden members are good for workloads with different usage patterns from the other members in the replica set.

Another option may be to configure a [Priority 0 Replica Set Member](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/replica-set-architecture-geographically-distributed/).

> Because delayed members are a "rolling backup" or a running "historical" snapshot of the data set, they may help you recover from various kinds of human error.

I am interested in these options myself, but I haven't decided what approach I will use.